# Error creating bean with name 'factory' defined in class path resource config.xml Invocation of init method failed

Tags: spring

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" name="factory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>    
        </props>
    </property>
    
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>
                com.cart.hibernate_crud.entity.Cart
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>
```

AND

I am using XML file for my configuration and when i try to run this application I get the error like Invocation of init method failed.

Comment: Hi please post full stacktrace of the error

Comment: I solved it. thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because original poster commented that he solved it without providing any details either to the question either an answer with the solution.